# Jackson annotations not used with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 1.0.1.RELEASE and am trying to get it to pick up some Jackson annotations. More specifically, I am trying to use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations. Any idea why this might get ignored? I also tried `@JsonIgnore` but that also did not seem to get picked up.

I already tried the 2 things mentioned [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881382/jsonignore-and-jsonbackreference-are-being-ignored) (Moving the Jackson annotionations to be first and using a `List` instead of a `Set`). I also looked at [this question on the Spring forums](http://forum.spring.io/forum/jpa-orm/747479-jsonmanagedreference-doesn-t-seem-to-do-anything), but that does not help me either.

UPDATE:

This is my `ComponentType` class:

```
@Entity
public class ComponentType
{
// ------------------------------ FIELDS ------------------------------

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private long m_id;

    private String m_name;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<ComponentSubtype> m_subtypes;

// --------------------------- CONSTRUCTORS ---------------------------

    public ComponentType()
    {
    }

    public ComponentType( String name, Iterable<ComponentSubtype> subtypes )
    {
        m_name = name;
        m_subtypes = Lists.newArrayList(subtypes);
    }

    // -------------------------- PUBLIC METHODS --------------------------

    public long getId()
    {
        return m_id;
    }

    public void setId( long id )
    {
        m_id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    public void setName( String name )
    {
        m_name = name;
    }

    public List<ComponentSubtype> getSubtypes()
    {
        return m_subtypes;
    }

    public void setSubtypes( List<ComponentSubtype> subtypes )
    {
        m_subtypes = subtypes;
    }

    public ComponentSubtype getSubtype( final long subtypeId )
    {
        return Iterables.find( getSubtypes(), new Predicate<ComponentSubtype>()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean apply( ComponentSubtype input )
            {
                return input.getId() == subtypeId;
            }
        } );
    }
```

And this is `ComponentSubtype`:

```
@Entity
public class ComponentSubtype
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue()
    private long m_id;

    private String m_name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private ComponentType m_componentType;

    public ComponentSubtype()
    {
    }

    public ComponentSubtype( String name )
    {
        m_name = name;
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        return m_id;
    }

    public void setId( long id )
    {
        m_id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    public void setName( String name )
    {
        m_name = name;
    }

    public ComponentType getComponentType()
    {
        return m_componentType;
    }

    public void setComponentType( ComponentType componentType )
    {
        m_componentType = componentType;
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/components")
public class ComponentTypeController
{
    @Autowired
    private ComponentTypeRepository m_repository;

    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public Iterable<ComponentType> listComponents()
    {
        return m_repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And the repository:

```
public interface ComponentTypeRepository extends CrudRepository<ComponentType, Long>
{
}
```

In my main I create some entities for testing:

```
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run( Main.class, args );
ComponentTypeRepository componentTypeRepository = context.getBean( ComponentTypeRepository.class );
componentTypeRepository.save( new ComponentType( "Component A", Sets.newHashSet( new ComponentSubtype( "Sub A - 1" ), new ComponentSubtype( "Sub A - 2" ) ) ) );
componentTypeRepository.save( new ComponentType( "Component B", Sets.newHashSet( new ComponentSubtype( "Sub B - 1" ), new ComponentSubtype( "Sub B - 2" ) ) ) );
componentTypeRepository.save( new ComponentType( "Component C", Sets.newHashSet( new ComponentSubtype( "Sub C - 1" ), new ComponentSubtype( "Sub C - 2" ) ) ) );
componentTypeRepository.save( new ComponentType( "Component D", Sets.newHashSet( new ComponentSubtype( "Sub D - 1" ),
                                                                                 new ComponentSubtype( "Sub D - 2" ),
                                                                                 new ComponentSubtype( "Sub D - 3" )
) ) );
```

If I point my browser to `http://localhost:8080/api/components/list`, then I get a stackoverflow exception.

This is part of the stacktrace I get:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:660)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:117)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:23)
```

EXAMPLE PROJECT that demonstrates the problem:

Download from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6373261/jackson-problem.zip

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using? Make sure it is the one supported by Spring Boot (e.g. by using the starter poms as dependencies - Jackson is included in the web starter).

Comment: I am using `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency and this seems to give me Jackson 2.3.2

Comment: OK, then it should work. What is it you are trying to do more precisely? Maybe put some code in the question?

Comment: I have added my code. Thank you for having a look. Is there any way that I can enable more debugging from Jackson?

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So what comes out of your endpoints? If it's JSON I guess Jackson is working, but your field-level annotations are not? Mayeb you could put a short section of the cycle from the exception in the question as well?

Comment: Added the stacktrace. I can confirm that none of the field-level annotations work. If I add a `@JsonProperty("foo")` on a field, then the JSON will still print the field name instead of the `foo` in the JSON. I am using Java 7 if that would matter.

Comment: Any chance they are the wrong annotations (maybe you have Jackson 1.9 on your classpath by mistake as well)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50697/discussion-between-dave-syer-and-wim-deblauwe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your (old-fashioned IMO) naming convention for fields ("m_*").
Jackson doesn't correlate them with the getters and setters. So you have to either `@JsonIgnore` the getters and setters, or change your naming, or annotate the getters. Or maybe there is a feature in `@JsonBackReference(...)`? `@JsonBackReference("componentType")` for instance, might work.

Comment: I ended up moving the annotations from the fields to the getters to fix it.